# Windows Powershell Environment Variables

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, powershell-2.0

I tried but did not find an answer :

**How do I get the current user home in Windows PowerShell?**

Answer (score 1):

System variables (those that you would address in Batch as `%varname%`) are accessible in PowerShell as `$env:varname`. You can list the system variables that are visible to your PowerShell session with `Get-ChildItem -Path Env:`.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, it looks like $env:userprofile or $env:homepath without the drive.

```
dir env: | where value -match admin


Name                           Value
----                           -----
APPDATA                        C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming
HOMEPATH                       \Users\admin
LOCALAPPDATA                   C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local
OneDrive                       C:\Users\admin\OneDrive
Path                           C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Wind...
PSModulePath                   C:\Users\admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerSh...
TEMP                           C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP                            C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp
USERNAME                       admin
USERPROFILE                    C:\Users\admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%UserProfile%")
```